# Solve $e^x \cdot 2y' = y^2 + y'^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve
> $$e^x \cdot 2y' = y^2 + y'^2.$$

**My Attempt**

Let $p = y'$ then $2e^x \cdot p=y^2+p^2$. No differentiate both sides to get:

$$2e^x \cdot p + 2e^x \frac{dp}{dx} = 2yp + 2p\frac{dp}{dx}$$

$$\frac{dp}{dx}(2e^x-2p) = 2yp-2e^xp \rightarrow \frac{dp}{dx}(e^x-p) = yp-e^xp$$

I can not easily identify this form so I make the substitution $y = ux$ and $y' = u'x + u$

$$(u'x+u)(e^x-ux) = yux-e^xux$$

Later manipulation does not really get me to an easier form, where should I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2e^x  \dfrac {dy}{dx} = y^2 + \left(\dfrac {dy}{dx}\right)^2$$
Substitute $u=e^x$:
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac {dy}{du}\dfrac  {du}{dx}=e^x \dfrac {dy}{du}=u\dfrac {dy}{du}$$
The DE becomes:
$$u^2(  2y' -  y'^2)=y^2$$
$$y=\pm u \sqrt {( 2y' -  y'^2)}$$
Here $y'$  means $\dfrac {dy}{du}$.This is [D'Alembert's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_equation). Maybe you can find a parametric solution.
$$y(u)=uf(y')+g(y')$$

Comment: I don't understand how your substitution produces $u^2(2y'-y'^2) = y^2$, there is only one $e^x$ in the original equation?

Comment: Oh because the $y'$ means $\dfrac {dy}{du}$  @A.RadekMartinez

Comment: I  changed a little my notation sinceit's a bit  confusing. But note that with D'Alembert differential equation you  can find at least a parametric solution. @A.RadekMartinez

Answer (score 2):

The form of the terms invites to complete the square to get
$$
e^{2x}=y^2+(y'-e^x)^2.
$$
This circle equation then can be used to introduce the trigonometric circle parametrization
$$
y(x)=e^x\sin(u(x)),~~~ y'(x)-e^x=e^x\cos(u(x)).
$$
As a consequence
$$
e^x(\sin(u(x))+\cos(u(x))u'(x))=y'(x)=e^x(1+\cos(u(x)))
\\
\implies 
u'=\frac{1+\cos(u)-\sin(u)}{\cos(u)}
$$
This can now be solved to at least implicit form by using standard methods (half-angle tangent, $u=2\arctan t$).